# How do I make certain images available when user selects certain boot image? [WDS]

Tags: boot, pxe-boot, windows-server-2012-r2, wds, wim

### I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Installation that is used for everything under the sun including Network installation services.

I would like to have the server offer certain images based upon the users selection of the boot image.

For example:
The user selects a `Windows 7 boot image`.
The system would only offer certain prespecified images (in this case `Windows 7 images`).

How would I accomplish this?

Currently the system offers ALL of the images available on the server. This is not a good idea in my opinion because some of them are W8, WV, WS2012 R2 Etc. I only want to offer the W7 images to that boot image.

---

The reason I want to do this is because I would like to use the corresponding Windows Setup for each boot image. E.G. Windows 7 Boot with Windows 7 install image etc...

Extra info:

The install images available on the server are as follows:

- All Windows Server 2012 R2 Images
- All Windows Server 2012 Images
- All Windows Server 2008 R2 Images
- All Windows Server 2008 Images includes
- All windows 8 Images
- All Windows 7 images
- All Windows Vista Images

All install images have their corresponding boot images.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a boot image, it contains the UNC path for accessing the Deployment Share which hold the task sequences (or install images).

If you did want to do this, you would need to setup a separate Deployment share for the different install images group you wanted to separate.

You would then generate the boot ISO and add it to your WDS server.

When booting clients, you could then select a boot image related to what you need to deploy.

For the record, this isn't the correct way of configuring MDT and WDS, in my opinion. There's no reason to split up the boot images based on OS as MDT doesn't care about what OS it's deploying.

Please add the reasoning as to why you want to do this on your original post.

Comment: So I should have a different Deployment share per install image?

Comment: Oops this question is out dated. I recently have started using MDT 2013 and it has taken care of my issues.

Comment: Oh, also, this is for MDT I am still interested in using pure WDS. MDT can take care of the issue but I am still interested in splitting up the install images based upon which boot image the client picks. REMEMBER, this is for WDS only, no other deployment system like sccm or mdt.